# Updating listbox selected index

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, listbox, google-forms, listboxitems

I have a google script which reads and writes between a google spreadsheet and a google form. It's basically a form to access a materials database.

When first accessing the form, it shows all the fields blank, a populated 'selector' listbox of material id's (CW_ID) and an option for "New" part in the selector listbox. If user stays on "New", the fields stay blank for user to populate them manually and appends it as a new item in the database. If user scrolls through the 'selector' listbox and selects a CW_ID, it will pull from the spreadsheet and populate the fields with data corresponding to the selected CW_ID, for the user to then edit (modify a detail about a part).

Because I am using a SQL structure for my database, I have a couple linked tables:

- materials table (which holds most information about the part, including an ID for manufacturer [manufacturer_ID])
- manufacturers table (which is linked to the materials.manufacturer_ID)

Right now, the form only uses the materials sheet to populate the fields, so in the field for 'manufacturer', it only shows the ID number. For user purposes, I want the script to check the manufacturer_ID shown in the materials sheet, go into manufacturers sheet, find a match and have the manufacturers listbox show it as the currently selected index. (Or just have the name of the manufacturer show up in the field)

This is part of my script so far:

(Scroll to bottom for "//****THIS IS THE PART I'M WORKING ON")

```
function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/something")
  var materialsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('materials');
  var manufacturersSheet = ss.getSheetByName('manufacturers');
  var vendorsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('vendors');
  var usersSheet = ss.getSheetByName('users');
  var projectApp = UiApp.createApplication();
  projectApp.setTitle("Materials Form");
  var activeEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  //I create the vertical panel.
  var panel = projectApp.createVerticalPanel().setId('face'); 


  //Here is where I actually create the drop down menu, and assign the function "goSelection" to be activated whenever a selection is made.
  var selector = projectApp.createListBox(true);
  selector.setName('selectionBox').setId('selectionBox').addItem('New');
  var materialsData = materialsSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  //do until row is less than length of 
  for (var i=0; i < materialsData.length; i++){ 
    if (materialsData [i][1] == "Email"){
      //if row in Column B does not equal gmail, skip to i++
      continue;
    }
    //add Column C (CW_ID) of current row to the selector list
    selector.addItem(materialsData [i][2]); 
  }
  selector.setSelectedIndex(0);
  var selectHandler = projectApp.createServerHandler('goSelection');
  selectHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  selector.addChangeHandler(selectHandler);



 //Here is where I create the drop down menu to show list of manufacturers from manufacturers sheet
  var manufSelectorLabel = projectApp.createHTML("<br><b>Manufacturer</b><br>").setWidth('100%');
  var manufSelector = projectApp.createListBox(true);
  manufSelector.setName('manufSelectionBox').setId('manufSelectionBox').addItem('New');
  var manufacturersData = manufacturersSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  //do until row is less than length of 
  for (var i=0; i < manufacturersData.length; i++){ 
    if (manufacturersData [i][1] == "Email"){
      //if row in Column B does not equal gmail, skip to i++
      continue;
    }
    //add Column C (Manufacturers) of current row to the selector list
    manufSelector.addItem(manufacturersData [i][3]); 
  }
  manufSelector.setSelectedIndex(0);
  var manufSelected = manufSelector.SelectedItem;'
  //**I am unsure whether this should have it's own function
  //var manufSelectHandler = projectApp.createServerChangeHandler('goManuf');
  //manufSelectHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  //manufSelector.addChangeHandler(manufSelectHandler);


  var gmailLabel = projectApp.createHTML("<br><b>Gmail:</b><br>").setWidth('100%');
  var gmailField = projectApp.createTextArea().setSize('100%', '25px');
  gmailField.setName('gmailArea').setId('gmailArea');
  gmailField.setText(activeEmail);

  var savedLabel = projectApp.createLabel('Thank you for your submission.');
  savedLabel.setVisible(false).setId('sLabel');

  //At this point, I'm actually declaring the variables for all the fields and text for the actual form. 
  var selectorLabel = projectApp.createHTML("<br><b>Select CW_ID from list.</b>").setId('selectLabel');  


  var descriptionLabel = projectApp.createHTML("<br><b>Description</b><br>").setWidth('100%');
  var descriptionField = projectApp.createTextArea().setSize('100%', '100px');
  descriptionField.setName('descriptionArea').setId('descriptionArea');    

  var manufacturerLabel = projectApp.createHTML("<br><b>Manufacturer</b></br>").setWidth('100%');
  var manufacturerField = projectApp.createTextArea().setSize('100%x', '25px');
  manufacturerField.setName('manufacturerArea').setId('manufacturerArea');    

  var manufacturerListLabel = projectApp.createHTML("<br><b>ManufacturerList</b></br>").setWidth('100%');
  var manufacturerListField = projectApp.createTextArea().setSize('100%x', '25px');
  manufacturerListField.setName('manufacturerListArea').setId('manufacturerListArea');

  var modelnumberLabel = projectApp.createHTML("<br><b>Model Number</b><br>").setWidth('100%');
  var modelnumberField = projectApp.createTextArea().setSize('100%', '25px');
  modelnumberField.setName('modelnumberArea').setId('modelnumberArea');   


  //Next, i create the save button and assign the function "saved" to be activated whenever the button is pressed.
  var saveButton = projectApp.createButton('Save');
  var saveHandler = projectApp.createServerHandler('saved');
  saveHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  saveButton.addClickHandler(saveHandler);

  //Now that all the componentes of the form have been declared and set up, I'm going to assemble them on the panel.
  panel.setSpacing(6);
  panel.add(nameLabel);
  panel.add(nameField);
  panel.add(gmailLabel);
  panel.add(gmailField);  
  panel.add(selectorLabel);
  panel.add(selector);
  panel.add(descriptionLabel);
  panel.add(descriptionField);
  panel.add(manufSelectorLabel);
  panel.add(manufSelector);
  panel.add(manufacturerLabel);
  panel.add(manufacturerField);
  panel.add(modelnumberLabel);
  panel.add(modelnumberField);
  panel.add(saveButton);
  panel.add(savedLabel);
  projectApp.add(panel);
  return projectApp;
}


  //This function looks to see what has been selected in the drop down menu, and then pulls the appropriate data from the spreadsheet to display in the fields.
   function goSelection(e){
  var activeEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var gmailField = app.getElementById('gmailArea');
  var nameField = app.getElementById('nameArea');
  var chosen = e.parameter.selectionBox;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/something")

  var materialsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('materials');
  var manufacturersSheet = ss.getSheetByName('manufacturers');
  var vendorsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('vendors');
  var materialsData = materialsSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var manufacturersData = manufacturersSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var vendorsData = vendorsSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var panel = app.getElementById('face');
  var standardpartField = app.getElementById('standardpartArea');
  var descriptionField = app.getElementById('descriptionArea');
  var manufacturerField = app.getElementById('manufacturerArea');
  var manufacturerListField = app.getElementById('manufSelectionBox');
  var modelnumberField = app.getElementById('modelnumberArea');

if (chosen != 'New') {
 for (var i=1; i < materialsData.length; i++){
    if (materialsData [i][1] == "Email"){
  //if row in Column B does not equal gmail, skip to i++
  continue;
   }
   if (materialsData [i][2] != chosen){
    continue;
    }
    nameField.setText(materialsData [i][0]);
    gmailField.setText(materialsData [i][1]);
    standardpartField.setText(materialsData [i][3]);
    descriptionField.setText(materialsData [i][4]);


    //****THIS IS THE PART I'M WORKING ON
    //set manufacturerField to manufacturer of current row
    //loop through manufacturer sheet until row matches with manufacturersField
    //when a match is found, selector box index to same row

    manufacturerField.setText(materialsData [i][5]);      

    for (var i=1; i < manufacturersData.length; i++){
      if (manufacturersData [i][1] == "Email"){
      //if row in Column B does not equal Email, skip to i++
        continue;
      }
      if (manufacturersData [i][2] != manufacturerField){
        continue;
      }
     manufacturerListField.setSelectedIndex(i);
    }

    modelnumberField.setText(materialsData [i][6]);
    }
}
```

This makes sense to me, but it doesn't work. I click on a part in the selector listbox, and all the info populates into the fields, as I want it to. However, the manufacturer listbox does not jump to the proper manufacturer (as populated in the manufacturer field), it just sits there and stays as is.

(See image to get an idea of what the form looks like)

http://oi61.tinypic.com/6h6tqp.jpg

Manufacturer listbox and field show up, but right now, only the manufacturer field changes to show the data when a part is selected)

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! :)

Comment: The UiApp class is now deprecated.  [Google Documentation - UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app)  You're putting effort and time into something that is unsupported and will get turned off in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some HTML that can get you started with the HTML Service:

### Input Form HTML

```
<div>
  <div>
      Name:
     <select>
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
      <option value="three">Three</option>
      <option value="four">Four</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br/>

  <div>
    Gmail:
     <select>
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
      <option value="three">Three</option>
      <option value="four">Four</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br/>

  <div>Select_CW_ID_From List:</div>
    <select name="CW_ID" multiple>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <br/>

  <div>Standard Part</div>

  <input type="text"/>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div>Description</div>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform">
Enter text here...</textarea>
</div>

<script>
  function onSuccess(argReturnValue) {
    alert('was successful ' + argReturnValue);
  }

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
      .nameOfFunctionInGS_File();
</script>
```

Download Notepad++:  [Notepad plus plus](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

And design your HTML in that.  Then create an HTML file in your Apps Script project.

Your `doGet()` should just have the code that serves the HTML.

### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {

  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myHTML_File_Name_Here')
    .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the NATIVE mode
    .setTitle('Materials Form')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
};
```

Create another `.gs` file for dealing with the data.  That's where all your code for writing data to the spreadsheet will go.

If you need to populate select boxes, you can do that with JavaScript in a script tag of the HTML.

With what I've given you, you should be able to create a Stand Alone Apps Script HTML Service app.  Publish it, and run it.  You probably did that with your current project.